# xamarin ios 10 open app store application programmatically in my app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

i'm trying to open app store application programmatically in my app.

what i'm trying to do is that i'm calling a service to check at the current app version and if it needs update i should open app store application to let the user update the my app.

*note: the app not published yet to the store, i'm still in coding phase.*

i tried to use the following code in ViewDidLoad method, but it's not working (nothing happened):

```
var nsurl = new NSUrl("itms://itunes.apple.com");
UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(nsurl);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A direct link via `itms:` will only work in an actual device, if you are testing on a simulator, use `https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/ios/id36?mt=8` instead.

I would recommend using `itms://` link on the actual device as it prevents the redirects that user sees when using a `https://` link to open iTunes.

```
bool isSimulator = Runtime.Arch == Arch.SIMULATOR;
NSUrl itunesLink;
if (isSimulator)
{
    itunesLink = new NSUrl("https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/ios/id36?mt=8");
}
else
{
    itunesLink = new NSUrl("itms://itunes.apple.com");
}
UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(itunesLink, new NSDictionary() { }, null);
```

Instead of opening the external Store app on the device, you might want to consider keeping the user inside of your app by using a `SKStoreProductViewController`:

```
bool isSimulator = Runtime.Arch == Arch.SIMULATOR;
if (!isSimulator)
{
    var storeViewController = new SKStoreProductViewController();
    storeViewController.Delegate = this;
    var id = SKStoreProductParameterKey.ITunesItemIdentifier;
    var productDictionaryKeys = new NSDictionary("SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier", 123456789);
    var parameters = new StoreProductParameters(productDictionaryKeys);
    storeViewController.LoadProduct(parameters, (bool loaded, NSError error) =>
    {
        if ((error == null) && loaded)
        {
            this.PresentViewController(storeViewController, true, () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SKStoreProductViewController Completed");
            });
        }
        if (error != null)
        {
            throw new NSErrorException(error);
        }
    });
}
else
{
    var itunesLink = new NSUrl("https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/ios/id36?mt=8");
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(itunesLink, new NSDictionary() { }, null);
}
```

Comment: Trying to get this to work from within a helper method. What could I assign to `storeViewController.Delegate`?

Comment: @hvaughan3 Really depends upon what your needs are: `ISKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate`, `SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate`, or `SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate_Extensions` In the example above, `ISKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate` was implemented on the `UIViewController` that I was launching the `SKStoreProductViewController` from

Answer (score 3):

```
NSBundle.MainBundle.InfoDictionary["CFBundleVersion"]
```

Returns you the current app version.

To open the Apple Appstore just let the user navigate to the appstore link, Apple will automaticly detect that the user is using an iPhone and will open the Appstore for them.

**Test yourself:**

Open the following link in safari: [Whatsapp in the Appstore](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/whatsapp-messenger/id310633997)

It will automatically open the appstore.

Answer (score 2):

When you create app on [iTunesConnect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/) you can get url to your future app in AppStore even if you didn't release it yet. You can find it under App Information tab:
[image]

In your app you can just open it:

```
var nsurl = new NSUrl("https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mygreatapp/id123456789");
UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(nsurl);
```