# Unable to open App Store from app programmatically

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I had been trying to open/navigate App Store from my application when there is a version upgrade.
For that I have written `customrender` which works perfectly fine for android. But it's not working for iOS. Following is the code written for iOS `customrenderer`. I attached the screenshot of the code in an attachment.

```
public class OpenAppStore : UIViewController, ISKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate, IOpenStore
{
    public void OpenStore()
    {
        bool isSimulator = Runtime.Arch == Arch.SIMULATOR;
        if (!isSimulator)
        {
            var storeViewController = new SKStoreProductViewController();
            storeViewController.Delegate = this;
            var id = SKStoreProductParameterKey.ITunesItemIdentifier;
            var productDictionaryKeys = new NSDictionary("SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier", 1389696261);
            var parameters = new StoreProductParameters(productDictionaryKeys);
            storeViewController.LoadProduct(parameters, (bool loaded, NSError error) =>
            {
                if ((error == null) && loaded)
                {
                    this.PresentViewController(storeViewController, true, () =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("SKStoreProductViewController Completed");
                    });
                }
                if (error != null)
                {
                    throw new NSErrorException(error);
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            var itunesLink = new NSUrl("https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/ios/id36?mt=8");
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(itunesLink, new NSDictionary() { }, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Problem : It doesn't throw any error. PresentViewController is called but it doesn't navigate/open my app in the App Store.

Thank you

Comment: First; do not post images as code, edit the question and place the formatted code directly in your question. Second; What actually is the problem you are having with the code?

Comment: I have made the asked changes. Please help! I have got this code from your post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40585028/xamarin-ios-10-open-app-store-application-programmatically-in-my-app

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't need a custom renderer for this. You should inject a simple helper class that will open the appropriate app store for each platform you support.
Secondly, the url you are using for the iOS App Store looks to be incorrect. Use something like:

```
var url = new NSUrl($"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-store/{myAppId}?mt=8");
```

The app store URL used above is from the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1629/_index.html). You can then open that url.